# Print a square with characters using 2D char arrays

Tags: java

Please help! The user should input the size of the square along with the characters they wish to fill it with. This is the code that I have right now:

```
Scanner myKey = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("\nHow many rows and columns (min 4 & max 20)? ");
        int rowCol1 = myKey.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Which character do you want to fill your square with? ");
        char symbol1 = myKey.next(".").charAt(0);

        char[][] choice1 = new char[rowCol1][symbol1];

        for (int i = 0; i<choice1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<choice1[i].length; j++) {
                choice1[i][j] = symbol1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<choice1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<choice1[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(choice1[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

My code is not correct. If I input, for example, 4 and @, the correct output should be:

```
@ @ @ @ 
@ @ @ @
@ @ @ @ 
@ @ @ @
```

Please help me fix my code so that I obtain the desired output. Thank you in advance

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: I see several problems with this code; allocating an array using the character as the length, for one.

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: If you input "4" and "A", I imagine your output is a 4 by 65 grid of "A"s, correct? You're providing incorrect size to the array initialization.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's the output I receive if I input "4" and "A". How can I provide the correct size to the array?

Comment: Consider the meaning of `new char[rowCol1][symbol1]`: how big is this array? Remember, the the values in the square brackets are *numbers* specifying the length.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are initializing the size of the array incorrectly. The second parameter should be the same as the first, since you want a square matrix where the number of rows and columns are equal. So, instead of using **symbol1** as the parameter for the number of columns, you should use the same variable which you use to define the number of rows - **rowCol1**

The line -

```
char[][] choice1 = new char[rowCol1][symbol1];
```

should replace **symbol1** with **rowCol1** since you want it to be a square matrix -

```
char[][] choice1 = new char[rowCol1][rowCol1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That definitely makes a lot more sense when assigning the size of the 2d array. Very much appreciated!